# do sessions work when cookies are disabled?

Tags: php, cookies, session

if the user has disabled cookies in the browser, do sessions work? cause i know there is a session cookie in the client when i create sessions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The session id can be appended to the URL, so, yes, they can.

Check out [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/2587.htm)

**Edit to answer additional question**

Cookies are the preferred method if you can help it. You should read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to get a better understanding. From the article if you don't read it:

> Transferring session identifiers as
>   HTTP cookies is more secure

Comment: is sending with url better in any way?